# Notepad++ autosave plugin not working

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I have installed notepad++ latest version but when i go to plugin manager and click on autosave to install but it gives error.

Also if i copy the autosave files in notepad++ files separately then i can see the plugin there , i did change the setting like save on lose focus but it is not saving files

Comment: What error does it give?  It sounds like you did get it to install, maybe? Is it doing anything at all?

Comment: IT gets installed and i can see the autosave plugin in the plugins menu but it is not working at all . i mean it not saving it , even after 4 hours. Did your plugin saves the files??

Comment: I haven't even managed to install this plugin

Comment: i also have to download the plugin separately and copy .dll file in notepad++/plugins folder to install it

Answer (score 4):

Yeah i have seen this same error for some time now.
You'll have to go to http://sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins
And download the latest.Unpack only the AutoSaveU.dll to C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins (this is for 64bit system.Regular Program Files for 32bit system).

Comment: yes the U one is for notetab unicode version.

Comment: Back in 2020, autosave is still not working and the link is dead. Congrats @tmrw for the first K.